# Android Tile Based UI for app

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I was wondering if anyone out there has attempted to create a similar feel that Windows phone provides (tile based UI) to an Android app. Overall what I would like is to have certain "tiles" displaying certain information. When the tile has a touch event, the tile will expand or start another activity or w/e displaying more information to the user. If there are any leads to an API that would be great too.

Thank you!

Comment: Try checking out [StaggeredGridView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/). You'll have to implement the clicks/animations, but it's a start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [StaggeredGridView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/) or depending on your needs, you could also use [QuiltView](https://web.archive.org/web/20140310133520/http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/)